# Im pretty confident there is a memory leak in my DemoTable Class?

Tags: java, android, xml

When the particular activity loads my heap jumps from around 16mb up to around 64mb! at first i thought it was caused by me resizing large png's in my drawable dir, but i have resized them to a much smaller size as they are only displayed small.

What I don't understand is when I quit the activity why the heap size does not reduce, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to solving this problem.

```
    public class DemoTable extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageView rBall;
    ImageView yBall;
    ImageView bBall;
    ImageView cBall;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        rBall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rBall);
        rBall.setOnTouchListener(this);

        yBall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yBall);
        yBall.setOnTouchListener(this);

        bBall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bBall);
        bBall.setOnTouchListener(this);

        cBall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cBall);
        cBall.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo_table);


    }

    float x, y = 0.0f;
    boolean moving = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moving = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (moving) {
                    x = event.getRawX() - v.getWidth() / 2;
                    y = event.getRawY() - v.getHeight() * 3 / 2;
                    v.setX(x);
                    v.setY(y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                moving = true;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        rBall = null;
        yBall = null;
        bBall = null;
        cBall = null;
        System.gc();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

There are 4 instances of rBall(11kb) 4 of yBall(12kb) and 1 each cBall(11kb) and bBall(7kb)
xml below....

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/table_demo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rBall"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/r_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rBall2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/r_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rBall3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/r_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rBall4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/r_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yBall"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/y_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yBall2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/y_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yBall3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/y_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yBall4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/y_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bBall"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/b_ball" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cBall"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c_ball" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It should not be the cause at all but, you are calling System.gc() before releasing references to your balls in the method onDestroy.

Comment: moved it, and your right, not the cause still 63.44mb when back is pressed

Comment: I think you need to not use `android:src` because each image view is getting it's own drawable loaded, not the same one. https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Ok done some more playing around and found that if i use the inbuilt monitor of android studios button 'Initiate GC' it will clear the heap size back to around 15mb, why then is the system.gc() line in my onDestroy() of the class not being called??

Comment: Actually there are only very rare conditions where calling `System.gc()` should be done manually. It should be up to the VM to decide when to perform garbage collection and you should not need to care about it. Additionally I'd be surprised, if you really need to "free" the ImageView members by setting them to null. Generally Java is very convenient regarding memory management and you should not need to care about this stuff in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, but still why when I exit the activity does the heap remain so high??

Comment: @PaulGeorge what do you mean by "exit the activity"?

Comment: It may take up to 2 GC cycles for unreferenced memory to be freed depending on the interaction of your objects and possible finalize hooks.

Comment: Karakuri - pressing back key either on screen or device 'back' key, returning to the parent activity.

@dpr - should I be spending a lot of time trying to resolve this then or just leave it with the comfort that after 2GC cycles (which makes sense, as I have to initiate GC twice from AS for it to clear). M concern is that if my app was installed on an older device it would OOM and crash.

Comment: Actually I'm not much into android to give a profound answer on this. For a regular Java application I'd leave it as is. The VM will execute GC more frequently if it is short on memory. That is 2 GC cycles will be executed in a short period of time, if there is really a need to do so. However given the limited resources available on older mobile devices additional actions might need to be considered. But I can't recommend anything out of the box...